# exponent problem solving

Tags: exponentiation

I came across a problem; $a^x=b^y=c^z$ and $b^2=ac$. It is required to show $\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{z}=\frac{2}{y}$. I have tried the following steps-

\begin{equation*}
b^2=ac \\
b=\sqrt{ac} \\
b=a^{1/2}\ast c^{1/2}
\end{equation*}
So 
\begin{equation*}
a^x=a^{1/2}\ast c^{1/2} \\
c^z=a^{1/2}\ast c^{1/2}
\end{equation*}

After that I tried to find the value of $x$ and $z$ but I could not solve it this way. Can anyone please show me how I can solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a^x=b^y=c^z=k\implies a=k^{1/x}$ etc.

$$\displaystyle b^2=ca\implies(k^{1/y})^2=k^{1/x}\cdot k^{1/z}$$

$$\displaystyle\implies k^{\frac2y}=k^{\frac1x+\frac1z} $$

Assuming $k\ne0,1,$

$$ \dfrac2y=\dfrac1x+\dfrac1z$$

Answer (score 3):

Taking logarithms, we get 
$$ x\log a = y \log b = z \log c $$
and $$ 2 \log b = \log a + \log c $$
Hence 
\begin{align*}
  \frac 2y &= \frac{2\log b}{y \log b}\\
           &= \frac{\log a}{y\log b} + \frac{\log c}{y \log b}\\
           &= \frac{\log a}{x \log a} + \frac{\log c}{z \log c}\\
           &= \frac 1x + \frac 1z
\end{align*}