# Relation between $x,y,z$....Exponent problem...

Tags: exponential-function, exponentiation, inverse

> The given equation is-
>
> $\sqrt[x]{75}
>   = \sqrt[y]{45} =\sqrt[z]{15}$

Now,it is required to prove $x+y=3z$.

I want the simplest possible solution.Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should remove the $=0$ part of the equations. The roots are never $0$.

Comment: $a^x\neq 0$ for $a>0$ whatever the value of $x$ is

Comment: Notice that $\sqrt[x]{75}=75^{\frac{1}{x}}=(3\times5^2)^{\frac{1}{x}}=3^{\frac{1}{x}}\times5^{\frac{2}{x}}$. Do you know how to solve now?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1292651/exponent-problem-solving

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the statement of the problem, we know that $$15^{y/z}=45$$ and $$15^{x/z}=75$$

Consider $$15^3=(45)(75)=(15^{y/z})(15^{x/z})=15^{\frac{x+y}{z}}$$

From properties of logarithms and exponents, we now have $$\frac{x+y}{z}=3$$ and the result is immediate from here.

Answer (score 1):

seperating them by pairs we get:
$$
\frac{1}{x}ln(75)=\frac{1}{z}ln(15)
$$
and
$$
\frac{1}{y}ln(45)=\frac{1}{z}ln(15)
$$
We can then use the fact that $ln(a*b)=ln(a)*ln(b)$ to show:
$$
\frac{ln(3)+2ln(5)}{x}=\frac{ln(5)+ln(3)}{z}
$$
and
$$
\frac{2ln(3)+ln(5)}{y}=\frac{ln(5)+ln(3)}{z}
$$
Rearranging gives:
$$
({ln(3)+2ln(5)}){z}=({ln(5)+ln(3)}){x}
$$
and
$$
({2ln(3)+ln(5)}){z}=({ln(5)+ln(3)}){y}
$$
We can then observe that by summating these simultaneously we get
$$
({3ln(3)+3ln(5)}){z}=({ln(5)+ln(3)})({y+x})
$$
 and thus dividing through by $(ln(5)+ln(3))$ we find that
$$
x+y=3z
$$

Comment: Your answer is really pretty, and I almost went that route.

Answer (score 0):

Since 
$$75^{\frac 1x}=15^{\frac 1z}\Rightarrow 75=15^{\frac xz}$$and$$45^{\frac 1y}=15^{\frac 1z}\Rightarrow 45=15^{\frac yz}$$
we have
$$15^3=75\times 45=15^{\frac xz}\times 15^{\frac yz}=15^{\frac xz+\frac yz}\Rightarrow 3=\frac xz+\frac yz.$$